# Modify order by list, move an element to the top

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM teams ORDER BY team_name
```

This will give the teams in the table as result, ordered by the team's name. But how to move an element to the beginning of the list?

I would like to have `Manchester United` at the first row, and the other teams after that in alphabetical order.

Comment: You could do an union of two queries, the first on your favorite team exclusively, and the second like your original query, but without your favorite team.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you could do is add an extra field, `IF(team_name='Machester United', 1, 2) AS team_one` and then do your ORDER BY like this: `ORDER BY team_one, team_name`

Comment: +1 This is probably the more flexible and more semantically correct solution (over mine).

Answer (score 1):

Split the query, and then add back together with a Union Query:

```
SELECT * FROM teams WHERE team_name="Manchester United"
UNION
SELECT * FROM teams WHERE team_name NOT LIKE "Manchester United" ORDER BY team_name
```